# Converting Insertion Sort pseudocode to running Java code

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, pseudocode, insertion-sort

I tried to convert this Insertion Sort pseudocode into java but don't get the right output.  Here is the pseudocode

```
INSERTION-SORT(A)
1 for j ← 2 to length[A]
2   do key ← A[j]
3     ▹ Insert A[j] into the sorted sequence A[1  j - 1].
4     i ← j - 1
5     while i > 0 and A[i] > key
6      do A[i + 1] ← A[i]
7         i ← i - 1
8     A[i + 1] ← key
```

And here is my Java code

```
public class Insertion {

    public static void print(int[] A){          
        for(int i = 0; i > A.length; i++){              
            System.out.print(A[i] + " ");               
            }           
        System.out.println(); 
    }

    public static void insertionSort(int[] A){          
        for(int j = 1; j < A.length; j++){

            int key = A[j];
            int i = j - 1;

            while(i >= 0 && A[i] > key){
                A[i + 1] = A[i];
                i = i - 1;
            }               
            key = A[i + 1];             
        }           
        print(A);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){         
        int[] x = {5,2,4,6,1,3};
          insertionSort(x);
    }
}
```

What prints out is just the same array A.  Not sorted or anything just {5,2,4,6,1,3}.

Comment: Knowing the basic idea it should be simple to write it on your own, you insert every item from the inordered array into an ordered one, on every insertion you keep it ordered by pushing the current item, until it no longer violates the order condition

Answer (score 1):

```
public class InsertionSort {

    private static long[] arr;

    /**
     * Run Insertion Sort algorithm
     *
     * @param array data structure used to run the algorithm
     */
    public static void run(long[] array) {
        arr = array;
        int j;

        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            long temp = arr[i];
            j = i;
            while (j > 0 && temp <= arr[j - 1]) {
                arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
                j--;
            }
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Insertion {

    public static void print(int[] A){

        for(int i = 0; i > A.length; i++){

            System.out.print(A[i] + " ");

            }

        System.out.println(); 
    }

    public static void insertionSort(int[] A){

        for(int j = 1; j < A.length; j++){

            int key = A[j];
            int i = j - 1;

            while(i >= 0 && A[i] > key){
                A[i + 1] = A[i];
                i = i - 1;
            }

            key = A[i + 1];

        }

        print(A);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] x = {5,2,4,6,1,3};
        insertionSort(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should detail your answer